# Animation XML calling images on SDCard

Tags: android, xml, animation, sd-card

So my app is to large for the Android Market so I'm having to figure out how to put my image files into a folder that will be downloaded after the app install. Heres the deal. The images are part of a frame by frame animation. I have my frame by frame animation set in an XML. Should I keep my XML inside my app? And if so how do I call the images on the SDCard from the XML? And if I'm totally off track please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I keep my XML inside my app?

You don't have a choice, if you want to define the `AnimationDrawable` as a resource.

> And if so how do I call the images on the SDCard from the XML?

You can't, if you want to define the `AnimationDrawable` as a resource.

> And if I'm totally off track please point me in the right direction.

An `AnimationDrawable` resource is not well suited to the technique you are trying. Either put the images in the APK, or manually construct your `AnimationDrawable` in Java code, or do not use `AnimationDrawable`.

Comment: I would put the Images in the APK but that makes my APK 300MB and I can't upload that to the market. So I'm guessing I want to follow this then? http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html

Comment: @Joshua Sutherland: You have *much* bigger problems. You have 16MB of heap space, not 300MB, let alone whatever 300MB would expand to once the PNGs or JPEGs are decompressed. I have a 4GB desktop that I am using to type this comment, and I am unconvinced *it* could handle what you're trying to do. Please make this an MP4 file and play it with `VideoView`. If that's unpalatable, you won't be able to use `AnimationDrawable`, but will have to do all of this yourself with low-level Canvas 2D drawing code, to deal with bitmap recycling, since you can't hold all of that in RAM.

Comment: Dude, I'm developing for a tablet with 1GB DDR2 of RAM. I'm pretty sure it can handle it. It's 300MB total images, divided by 8 since its 8 separate animations. I'm fairly confident that it will work. However, this VideoView sounds interesting. It'll ruin another 14 hours of my life to rendering but I'll look into it. (and the emulator has 48MB heap space... and so does my Eris...)

Comment: @Joshua Sutherland: On a tablet, you have maybe a 32MB heap, possibly less. The size on disk of your images is not the relevant figure; it's the size once decompressed. And don't forget that your application is presumably doing something more than playing a 40MB animation. If your Eris has 48MB of heap space, you must be running a modded ROM, or ran an app to increase the heap, because the default on that device is 24MB.

Comment: Actually thats all it would be doing. Unless I get some more images from some people I'm working with it would be just a 40MB animation. I may have found something else that will work though. And yes, I'm running a modded ROM